# Replace a variable string in vbs

Tags: string, vbscript

i need to replace a string timestamp(n) with a fix string6) in vbs. where n can be any value and find string should be case insensitive.

strLine = fle1.ReadLine

'strLine = (replace(strLine,"TIMESTAMP(0)","TIMESTAMP(6) ")

Please help me this for any value of n.

Comment: Could you show an example (or multiple examples of) `strline` and what your desired output would be. It's not clear what you mean by `TIMESTAMP(0)`, `TIMESTAMP(6)`, and `STRING(6)` since VBS doesn't have any of those types natively and the languages that do, differ in how they are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regexp .[Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "TIMESTAMP\(\d+\)"
>> For Each s In Split("TIMESTAMP(1) TIMESTAMP(11) TIMESTAMP(9)")
>>     WScript.Echo s, r.Replace(s, "TIMESTAMP(6)")
>> Next
>>
TIMESTAMP(1) TIMESTAMP(6)
TIMESTAMP(11) TIMESTAMP(6)
TIMESTAMP(9) TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace but you can't omit any of the optional parameters.

> strLine = Replace(fle1.ReadLine,  "TIMESTAMP(0)", "TIMESTAMP(6) ", 1, -1, 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'regEx.Pattern = "(TIMESTAMP\([0-9].?\))"
    'regEx.IgnoreCase = True

    'strLine=regEx.Replace(strLine, "TIMESTAMP(6)")
```

I finally did it as i am very new to it, but learning things 
btw many thanks for help.